# how to use reflection the class which is not available in the package

Tags: java, reflection

How to create `Class.forName("some package")` which is not avalible in current package but it is running in the same JVM?

```
String jsConfigUpdatePkg = "com.baidu.openrasp.config.JSConfigUpdate";
Class<?> jcConfigClass = Class.forName(jsConfigUpdatePkg); // convert string classname to class
Class[] argTypes = new Class[] { String[].class };
Method updateConfigMethod = jcConfigClass.getDeclaredMethod("updateConfig", argTypes);
```

I'm getting `ClassNotFoundException` while doing `Class.forName("some package")`

Comment: what do you mean by "not avalible in current package"? is the package available in the classpath of the class laoder? if you can write `com.baidu.openrasp.config.JSConfigUpdate.class` and pass compilation and run, then you sohuld be able to load the class with `Class.forName()`. otherwise you will have to use a class loader that can locate the jar where the package resides

Comment: actually if you know tha java agents.i have 2 java agents which i'm attaching like java -javaagent:agent-1.jar -javaagent:agent-2.jar -jar <APP.JAR> ..here ..i try to create reflection from agent-1.jar the class is avaible in agent-2.jar...so is this possible?

Comment: like i said. you can load a class if it exists in the classpath. jar of agent2 has to be present in classpath of agent1

Answer (score 0):

this below code works if you want access to loadded jar instance.

Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass("com.Test");